# Steps to install Ubuntu 13.04 on a separated unallocated partition in dual boot with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

I doesn't know how to install Ubuntu 13.04, from pen drive, along with windows 10 OS. I have already make a partition of 100 GB for Ubuntu. It shows now as unallocated. How to allocate it?

Comment: Here is the link to do this follow this : http://askubuntu.com/a/221930/615726

Answer (score 0):

See a nice tutorial at http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html. Be sure that you understand what you will be doing before doing it.

Essentially,

1. Make a bootable USB flash drive containing Ubuntu.
2. Shut down Windows, for real. Windows 10 does not normally shut down for real in order to fool the users into thinking that it boots very quickly; use Google to find out how to shut down Windows for real.
3. Boot from the flash drive prepared in step 1.
4. Install Ubuntu in the free space available on the hard disk.

By the way, there is no such thing as an unallocated *partition*. Disk space is either in a partition or unallocated.

Ubuntu 13.04 is very very old. The current Long Term Support version is 16.04. Unless you have a very specific reason to use 13.04 you should be installing 16.04.

Comment: Is 16.04 better? If it so can I follow the step mentioned above?

Comment: 16.04 is three years newer, and, most importantly, _supported_, which means that it receives regular security updates. 13.04 is no longer supported (and it wasn't a Long Term Support version anyway). Read the linked article, it provides a step-by-step procedure.

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.